# ParallelMap returns incorrect results over Map

Tags: parallelization, map

I've written a function to pull in the useful column of a large data file:

```
ImportNthColumn[fname_, n_] := With[{
  command = "!awk '{ print $" <> ToString[n] <> " }' "
 },
  Flatten@Import[command <> fname, "Table"]
]
```

and I'd like to apply this function to pull in data from every subdirectory, like so:

```
ImportNthColumnFromDirectories[dirs_, fname_, n_] := With[{
  targets = Map[# <> "/" <> fname&, dirs]
},
  Map[ImportNthColumn[#,n]&, targets]
]
```

When I use `ImportNthColumnFromDirectories` with a serial map, everything works perfectly. When I use `ParallelMap`, however, the data in the *first* and *last* elements of `dirs` import correctly but all other iterations return a zero-length list. What could cause this strange behavior?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? Without your data files it's hard to say much of anything. One thing you could do is use head on each of the files to make smaller versions that you could then upload.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation say:

> ```
> Import["!prog","format"] imports data from a pipe.
> ```

I suggest that ParallelMap sent many requests to external program in one time and it return errors, but `Mathematica` interpret errors as empty list.

PS: sorry for my english